# Java System.out.println repeated 3 times when using System.in.read()

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having problems with the following code:

```
public class DWDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    char ch;

    do {
      System.out.print("Press a key followed by enter: ");
      ch = (char) System.in.read(); // get the char
    } while (ch != 'q');
  }
}
```

For some reason the System.out line is repeated 3 times. Example output from the console is here:

```
Press a key followed by enter: a
Press a key followed by enter: Press a key followed by enter: Press a key followed by enter:
```

I have tried this code in both Eclipse Kepler and manually compiling with the same issues. Googling the answer has proven to be fruitless. Any thoughts?

**Added correct code**

If I type more than 1 character I get 4 System.out.println results:

```
Press a key followed by enter: aa 
Press a key followed by enter: Press a key followed by enter: Press a key followed by     enter: Press a key followed by enter:
```

Comment: I don't see any `read()` method used in your code.

Comment: Did you post the correct code snippet?

Comment: Interesting...I am following code from Java: A Beginners Guide 5th Edition by Oracle and their example code does not reference a read method.

Comment: Sorry just fixed the code. First StackOverflow question! :|

Comment: what happens when you type more than just 1 char for input?

Comment: or better yet, what happens if you don't press enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press enter, it reads two extra characters in **windows** based system (\r\n).

If you change your code as :

```
    do {
        System.out.print("Press a key followed by enter: ");
        ch = (char) System.in.read(); // get the char
        char ch1 = (char) System.in.read(); // carriage return
        char ch2 = (char) System.in.read(); // line feed
    } while (ch != 'q');
```

It will print single "Press a key followed by enter: "

If you want to cross verify, print the int values of `ch1` and `ch2`, you will get `13` and `10` respectively.

Comment: If you're running it on Windows. If you're using Mac OS X or Linux, in which a single `\n` linefeed character is used for end-of-line, it might not work correctly.

Comment: Correct, hence I mentioned "Windows" in the answer.

Comment: Fantastic! This also helps me understand that read() appears to be per instance so as long as you instantiate a new read() the var assigned to it will retain what was in it?

Comment: I understand that there are probably much better ways to receive data from the console (if that is even a good idea in the first place) but if we were to stick with just the System.in.read how could this be applicable to any OS instead of just limited to a windows answer?

Comment: You may want to try "Scanner" class. That has some good values to read input from input stream (e.g. console).

Answer (score 7):

So you press a and hit enter. You'll then read these characters

- The character 'a'
- The character '\r'
- The character '\n'

(This applies to Windows, on e.g. *nix systems the newline would be just a '\n' instead of \r\n)

You could skip over e.g. all whitespace:

```
 do {
   System.out.print("Press a key followed by enter: ");
    ch = (char) System.in.read(); 
    while(Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        ch = (char) System.in.read(); 
    }
} while (ch != 'q');
```

Comment: Where `\r` is carriage return and `\n` is linefeed.

Comment: Thank you! It makes total sense now. I wonder why the book does not broach this subject.

Comment: It turns out that the book does cover this a few pages later. Perhaps it would be helpful for most students to see this in advance however.